# C++ difference between : , :: operators

Tags: c++

I new to programming. In stack overflow i couldn't see difference between `:` & `::` is mentioned. Could anyone can explain in detail it helps to beginner learners like me. Thank you.

Comment: Go get a book on C++, and start reading. The book will explain everything.

Comment: Since you are a beginner, like me, I feel the need to kindly educate you. While stack overflow is a great resource for asking questions, that question is against community guidelines because: 1) it is something you MUST learn in order to use C++ at all, so everyone already knows it after a few months; 2) it is an easily researchable question, that is easy to Google; 3) the question isn't addressing a specific problem you are trying to solve. It is a general knowledge question. 

I know it sucks to get down voted, but the question is rather like asking a carpenter why he needs a hammer.

Answer (score 2):

So you would use `::` when you're defining/using methods from a class, so like for example

```
class foo{

public:
int bar;
int hi(int x);

int func(); // static member function

Foo(int num): bar(num) {}; // use of a colon, initialization list

};

int foo::hi(int x){
//define the function
}
```

Also if you have static member functions, you can just call those whenever through using `foo::func()`. You can find more about static member functions online.

The single colon is for member initialization list (you can look this topic up online) where you can initialization member variables in the construction of your class.

You can also find single colon used in polymorphism, when you derive a class from a base class. You can find more information about c++ polymorphism online.